# how to get radio button with the same id

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, radio-button

I have a radio button. I have 2 radio button for different use, one is for displaying the ukuran and the other is for displaying the jenis. The radio button value is generated from database. I want to get the radio button value then when both of them is click I want to search to database with that certain value. Can anyone help me?

I try this

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <a class="active" href="#">
            <span>Jenis Produk </span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php 
foreach($jenis as $jns){
?>
    <input type="radio" id="jenis_produk" name="jenis_produk" value="<?php echo $jns['jenis_id'];?>">
    <label><?php echo $jns['jenis_produk'];?></label><br>
<?php 
} 
?>
    <li>
        <a href="#"> <span>Ukuran</span></a>
    </li>
<?php 
foreach($ukuran as $size){
?>
    <input type="radio" id="ukuran_produk" name="ukuran_produk" value="<?php echo $size['ukuran_id'];?>">
    <label><?php echo $size['size'];?></label><br>
<?php 
} 
?>
</ul>
```

Thank You :)

Comment: `id` is supposed to be unique in a page. You are generating yours in a loop

Comment: `foreach` and hardcoded `id=` wont mix, make it dynamic using iteration key etc, also `for="male"` is not going to work it needs match the id. avoid asking multiple questions, querying db via form or ajax is too broad as you have not made any effort to do it.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use following in the controller to get values

```
$jenis = $this->input->post("jenis_produk");
$ukuran = $this->input->post("ukuran_produk");
```

Then pass it to a model and

```
$sets = array("jenis" => $jenis,
                         "ukuran" => $ukuran);
$result = $this->db->where($sets)->get("table_name")->result_array();
```